# Suspected Places for Mac App Store Files

Tags: mac-appstore

I know that Evernote has about 4 gigs of stuff in my file system. I know this because I recently switched to a non-app-store version of Evernote and it "copied" my files and listed them at 2GB.

I want to start fresh with Evernote. Where can I look for all this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're planning to do, but here goes

> ~/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/

Tread carefully or else… Evernote may not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Response from Evernote Support on starting from scratch (Feb 13, 2013). Obviously, instead of moving stuff, you can just delete it:

---

Please try moving your Evernote database directory so that Evernote will regenerate a new local database by copying your notes back down from the service. To do this:

1. Your database is in a hidden directory. You can access it by opening the Finder, then selecting "Go" from the top menu and hitting the "Option" key. Once you have done that, you'll see the "Library" folder pop up.
2. Select it.
3. Then, go to:
   ~/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/ and move the "your username" directory to another place.
4. Once you've done that, please *also* go to:
   ~Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/Evernote/ and move the "your username" directory to another place.
   Note: You may not have a directory in both places. Please remove whichever ones you *do* have, and make sure that you no longer have either before moving forward.
5. Then, try opening Evernote again. All of your notes from the service will now synchronize and create a new local database.

*If you do have any Local Only notebooks, right-click the notebook name in the left-hand notebook pane and select "Export", then export the notebook to .enex format, exporting tags if desired. If you have some unsynchronized notes, you can go to the Note List view, sort by the "Sync" column, and export any notes that have a * in that column to .enex format before following the above instructions. Once those instructions are finished, you can then import the .enex files you created to restore these exported notes.

Comment: Good (and authoritative) answer. Thanks for sharing.